# Google Tag Manager event tracking not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to integrate GTM event tracking with android app.
I have done the following configurations

1. Created GTM and GA account
2. Added external account(GA) in GTM configuration.
3. Added Tag with Tag Type : Universal Analytics and Track ID of GA. Track Type: event (Tried with AppView too)
4. Added firing rule as Always
5. Configured android app to get the static container instance.
6. call pushEvent() to send the event using DataLayer.

When I run the application it is showing the log "Sending hit to service....." with the correct GA ID and event name.

But events are still not reflecting in the GA dashboard.

Did I miss any configurations or settings..?
Does the events tracking data will reflect immediately or will take time.? If it takes time, how much time it will take to update in the GA interface.?

Thank you in advance for the replay.

Comment: If you are checking in the Standard reports, then the data may not appear there right away - you will need to wait at least 24 hours. But if you check in Real-Time reports, then barring any problems, you should see your hits there.

Comment: I have checked in both Real time data and App overview. It is not appearing in both places.

Comment: It usually takes 24 hours to reflect the events and pageviews on Google Analytics. If you are still not getting any events can you show us the rules that you have added ?

Comment: Yes it is showing now, it is taking 24 hours to show up. Is there is any way it can me made to show up in the real time.

Comment: Real-time reports should show results right away. When testing analytics in native apps, I usually connect the device through an HTTP proxy so I can verify that the analytics requests are firing and are sending the proper data. Using a proxy this way will help determine if the problem is in the code in the device or with the reporting engine configuration.

Comment: @RajeshHegde Have you solved it? I'm stuck with the same problem. This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672360/how-to-configure-android-google-tag-manager-v4-with-google-analytics-universal

Comment: Make sure that there are no filters that are discarding your hits in your Google Analytics (GA) view or property (like IP, ISP, hostname, ...). To check if you have any filters defined, go to Admin -> Account -> All Filters